# How to retrieve data of a particuler child in firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

I tried this but I get a null pointer exception.

The username is used as the name of the child

```
private void getdataofuser() {
    String  Username = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername().toString();
    Query query = myreff.child("UserprofileNameAndregnumber").child(Username);
    query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            STUDENT_MODEL student_model = new STUDENT_MODEL();
            student_model.setPROFILE_NAME(snapshot.child("profile_NAME").getValue().toString());
            student_model.setREGNUMBER(snapshot.child("regnumber").getValue().toString());

            profilename.setText(student_model.getPROFILE_NAME().toString());
            REgnumber.setText(student_model.getREGNUMBER().toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            recreate();
        }
    });

}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCWIA.png)

Comment: Where exactly are you getting null pointer exception?

Comment: Please share the crash report.

Comment: First of all, stop ignoring errors. Use `Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage());`. Do you get something printed out in the logcat? Besides that, what's the value of `Username` in your reference?

Comment: Thanks bro i will check the logcat now for possible error message

Answer (score 0):

Try this code below. It will retrieve the data for a particular child

```
String  Username = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername().toString();
Query nameQuery = myreff.orderByChild("UserprofileNameAndregnumber").equalTo(Username);


nameQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.exists()) {
            for (DataSnapshot nameSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
                String getProfileName = nameSnapshot.child("profile_NAME").getValue(String.class);
                String getRegNumber = nameSnapshot.child("regnumer").getValue(String.class);
            }
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, "User Not Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        recreate();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you sir the code is little bit working but it get only blank space from the base instead of getting the value

Comment: There must be something wrong with the child. Maybe you can change instead of having "kdfb" as a child after your "UserprofileNameAndregnumber", try to add 1 more child after "UserprofileNameAndregnumber". For example : "UserprofileNameAndregnumber" -> "username" -> "kdbf". And dont forget to change your query

Comment: thanks bro it really help me to figure out the problem sir i really appreciate

Comment: You are welcome, sir. If you found my answer useful, you can accept my answer. It will be much appreciated. Thanks!